# Python pandas. how to delete date rows by condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe with dates as index, dates from 2013 year to 2018 year
how can i delete all rows  where year < 2018? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd4XG.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.